# How to update, pause, and clear FigureCanvasTkAgg canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to create Game of Life with python, matplotlib, numpy, and tkinter. After the user has entered the number of rows, columns, and probability of spawning a live cell, the user will then press the "generate" button to start the game. I am able to display the first canvas, but beyond that the program seems to be unable to update the canvas. When updating (using the while loop), I want the program to first call a function that updates the canvas, then pause the graph for 0.5 seconds, and finally clear the canvas so the next updated canvas can be displayed. I seem to have the most problem with FigureCanvasTkAgg (I am pretty new to tkinter), since it doesn't seem to accept the pause and delete attribute. Is there another way to update, pause, and clear the canvas?
Here are my codes:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from board import Board
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import time

iteration = 0
def num():
    global iteration
    iteration += 1
    n1 = int(t1.get())
    n2 = int(t2.get())
    n3 = int(t3.get()) / 100.00
    initBoard = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    for row in range(0,n1):
            for column in range(0,n2):
                initBoard[row][column] = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 2), p = [1 - n3, n3])
    game_board = Board(n1, n2, initBoard)
    user_input = ''
    while user_input != 'q':
        if user_input == '':
            game_board.update_board()
            ax.imshow(initBoard)
            canvas.draw_idle()
            ax.delete('all')

root = Tk()
root.title('Game of Life')
root.geometry('800x600')

#top = Toplevel(root)
Label(root, text="How many rows?: ").grid(row = 0)
Label(root, text="How many columns?: ").grid(row = 1)
Label(root, text="Probability of spawn (between 0 and 100): ").grid(row = 2)

t1 = Entry(root)
t2 = Entry(root)
t3 = Entry(root)

t1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
t2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
t3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

Button(root, text = 'Generate', command = num).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 4)

fig= plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('off')
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 4, column = 0)

mainloop()
```

Here is where Board and update_board() leads to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from tkinter import *

class Board:
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, game_board):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.initBoard = game_board
    
    def update_board(self):
        for row in range(0, self.rows):
            for column in range(0, self.columns):
                check_neighbour = self.check_neighbour(row, column)
                living_neighbours_count = 0
                for neighbour_cell in check_neighbour:
                    if neighbour_cell == 1:
                        living_neighbours_count += 1
                
                if self.initBoard[row][column] == 1:
                    if living_neighbours_count < 2 or living_neighbours_count > 3:
                        self.initBoard[row][column] = 0
                else:
                    if living_neighbours_count == 3:
                        self.initBoard[row][column] = 1

    def check_neighbour(self, check_row, check_column):
        search_min = -1
        search_max = 2
        neighbour_list = []
        for row in range(search_min, search_max):
            for column in range(search_min, search_max):
                neighbour_row = check_row + row
                neighbour_column = check_column + column

                valid_neighbour = True

                if (neighbour_row) == check_row and (neighbour_column) == check_column:
                    valid_neighbour = False

                if (neighbour_row) < 0 or (neighbour_row) >= self.rows:
                    valid_neighbour = False

                if (neighbour_column) < 0 or (neighbour_column) >= self.columns:
                    valid_neighbour = False

                if valid_neighbour:
                    neighbour_list.append(self.initBoard[neighbour_row][neighbour_column])
        return neighbour_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I think the below is what you want. I have it visibly changing every 500ms so, it's definitely some progress. I had to rewrite/reformat your main `tkinter` part. It was a big mess, so I cleaned it up.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

class Board:
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, game_board):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.initBoard = game_board
    
    def update_board(self):
        for row in range(0, self.rows):
            for column in range(0, self.columns):
                check_neighbour = self.check_neighbour(row, column)
                living_neighbours_count = 0
                for neighbour_cell in check_neighbour:
                    if neighbour_cell == 1:
                        living_neighbours_count += 1
                
                if self.initBoard[row][column] == 1:
                    if living_neighbours_count < 2 or living_neighbours_count > 3:
                        self.initBoard[row][column] = 0
                else:
                    if living_neighbours_count == 3:
                        self.initBoard[row][column] = 1

    def check_neighbour(self, check_row, check_column):
        search_min = -1
        search_max = 2
        neighbour_list = []
        for row in range(search_min, search_max):
            for column in range(search_min, search_max):
                neighbour_row = check_row + row
                neighbour_column = check_column + column

                valid_neighbour = True

                if (neighbour_row) == check_row and (neighbour_column) == check_column:
                    valid_neighbour = False

                if (neighbour_row) < 0 or (neighbour_row) >= self.rows:
                    valid_neighbour = False

                if (neighbour_column) < 0 or (neighbour_column) >= self.columns:
                    valid_neighbour = False

                if valid_neighbour:
                    neighbour_list.append(self.initBoard[neighbour_row][neighbour_column])
        
        return neighbour_list
        
        
class App(tk.Tk):
    WIDTH  = 800
    HEIGHT = 600
    TITLE  = 'Game Of Life'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        self.iteration=0
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax  = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.axis('off')
        
        tk.Label(self, text="How many rows?: ").grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="How many columns?: ").grid(row=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Probability of spawn (between 0 and 100): ").grid(row=2)
        
        self.t1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.t2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.t3 = tk.Entry(self)
        
        self.t1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.t2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.t3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        
        tk.Button(self, text='Generate', command=self.plot).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w', pady=4)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=0)
        
    def plot(self):
        n1 = int(self.t1.get())
        n2 = int(self.t2.get())
        n3 = int(self.t3.get()) / 100.00
        self.initBoard = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    
        for row in range(0,n1):
            for column in range(0,n2):
                self.initBoard[row][column] = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 2), p = [1 - n3, n3])
        
        self.game_board = Board(n1, n2, self.initBoard)
        self.update()
        
    def update(self):
        self.game_board.update_board()
        self.ax.imshow(self.initBoard)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.after(500, self.update)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.mainloop()
```